# Edittext.setmaxLines(3) programmatically not working

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, line

I am trying to draw text fields programmatically. These fields are dynamic, so that the size is variable according to the text that comes. The problem is that although I put `setMaxLines (3)`, if the text has 4 lines, draw all four. I have tried in several ways

```
    final CustomEditText edit_text = new CustomEditText(activity, idEtiqueta);
    edit_text.setLayoutParams(etLparams);

    edit_text.setFocusable(true);
    edit_text.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    edit_text.setTextSize(textSize);
    edit_text.setHint(ventaArrayList.get(i).getValorDefecto());

    edit_text.setTag(ventaArrayList.get(i));
    if (tipoCampo.equals(INPUTALFA) || tipoCampo.equals(INPUT))
    {
        //edit_text.setSingleLine(false);
        edit_text.setMaxLines(3);
        edit_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
    }else
        edit_text.setSingleLine(true);

    edit_text.setText(ventaArrayList.get(i).getValorDefecto());
    edit_text.setVisibility(visibilidad);
    edit_text.setEnabled(habilitado);
    //Escogemos el tipo de teclado según el tipo del campo
    if (tipoCampo.equals(INPUT) || tipoCampo.equals(CODIGOBARRAS))
        edit_text.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    else if (tipoCampo.equals(IMPORTESPRODUCTO))
        edit_text.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
```

The result is the text field with the lines that come, when what I really need is to cut the text so that only 3 are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your `CustomEditText` object if there's any logic.

If not, and it is considered a *normal* `EditText` try it like this:

```java
 if (tipoCampo.equals(INPUTALFA) || tipoCampo.equals(INPUT))
    {
        edit_text.setLines(3); // <-- Use setLines() instaed
        edit_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
    } else

        (...)
```

Comment: Mi problem was the line setHint. It was already when I deleted it! Thanks you so much for your answer.

Comment: If it helped don't forget to upvote and validate the answer.